# ec2, ping and security settings

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat

Got a noob question about security settings on AWS ec2 instance. I've set up an instance with Tomcat7 ( ami-95da17fc ) and I have a little issue.

If I ssh into the instance and do ping -c 2 -p 80 localhost I get 0 packet loss
if I ping my elastic ip I get 100% pocket loss, same thing with the long.winded.aws.dns.name

if I simply try to ping the site from terminal (not logged into the instance) I also get 100% pocket loss.

My default security group has the following settings:

0 - 65535   sg-07787e6e (default)

80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0

8080 (HTTP*)    0.0.0.0/0

22 (SSH)    70.126.98.72/32

I'd be most grateful if anyone can shed some light on what I'm missing.

---

... hm, I get 404 with curl, sudo netstat -lp gives me:

> Active Internet connections (only servers)
>   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
>   tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      841/sshd
>   tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LISTEN      868/sendmail: accep 
>   tcp        0      0 *:webcache                  *:*                         LISTEN      981/java
>   tcp        0      0 *:http                      *:*                         LISTEN      948/httpd
>   tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      841/sshd
>   tcp        0      0 localhost:8005              *:*                         LISTEN      981/java
>   tcp        0      0 *:8009                      *:*                         LISTEN      981/java
>   udp        0      0 *:bootpc                    *:*                                     734/dhclient
>   udp        0      0 domU-12-31-39-09-A6:ntp     *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   udp        0      0 localhost:ntp               *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   udp        0      0 *:ntp                       *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   udp        0      0 fe80::1031:39ff:fe0:ntp     *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   udp        0      0 localhost:ntp               *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   udp        0      0 *:ntp                       *:*                                     852/ntpd
>   Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
>   Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node PID/Program name    Path
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1954   922/gam_server      @/tmp/fam-root-
>   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1967   927/bluepilld: host /var/bluepill/socks/hostmanager.sock

... and I've not changed anything in iptables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol - the security groups in AWS Console default to the TCP protocol. If you wish to be able to ping your instance from 'the outside', you need change the security group settings to permit the ICMP protocol (Echo), using, for instance, something like the following:

```
ec2-authorize default -P icmp -t -1:-1 -s 0.0.0.0/0
```

You can also use the AWS Console to accomplish this:

- Create a 'Custom ICMP Rule' for your security group
- Type: Echo Request and Type: Echo Reply (both are required)
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Alternatively, for the same effect as the ec2-authorize command above, you can allow 'All ICMP'

See the [AWS EC2 Docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html) for more information, and the [AWS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1#18).

Comment: to follow up, is this in any way related why I can't see index.html placed in /var/www/html/ from the outside?

Comment: It shouldn't be - if you have a web server running on port 80, and port 80 is open in your security group, you should be able to access the page from the outside. Ensure your web server is running on port 80 with netstat, and use curl to retrieve the page from the instance (i.e. to rule out security group issues). Also check your iptables rules if you have changed them.

Comment: ... checked with netstat and curl, posted in answer form for readability.